# PyODBC to Access

Tags: connection, odbc

I'm using PYODBC and I defined on my Desktop a ODBC connection which I can connect to with conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=nameofftheDB'). This works great.

I defined on my work laptop the same ODBC connection and then it gives the error HY000 when I run my Python program. I think my connection is correct, via Excel I can load data via this ODBC connection.

I think it has to do with an autorisation policy of my employer so maybe I have to change something in the registry, however I've no clue what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It had to do with the ownership of the Access DB. During a copy process my employer became the owner of the Database. When I was able to change it it worked as wanted.